# Create CSV file without saving it into file system

Tags: java, csv, spring-mvc, spring-boot, inputstream

I've created a Java program to create a `csv` file, write data into it and then send its contents to the server.

Locally, everything works fine. But the problem is that I don't have write access to the server (permission denied problem).

So, I can't do any `chmod 777`.

I'm looking for a way to create a `csv` file without saving into the file system. Something like write into a flow or a stream. I don't really know how it works.
Any help please ?

This was what I have done so far:

```
  public void exportAllToCSV(@PathVariable int id,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
 String csvFile="test.csv";
 File file = new File("test.csv");
 //some treatments to get datas (headers and values)


  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);
  CsvBuilder.writeLine(writer, headers);
  CsvBuilder.writeLine(writer, values);
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
  response.setContentType("text/csv");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + csvFile);
  final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

  try {
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.getWriter().write(line + "\n");
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

    try {
        file.delete(); // I delete the file
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a file? Why don't you write the CSV file directly to `response.getWriter()`?

Comment: You can't write the file without saving it. "Save" means you write the file and close it.

Comment: Why don't you read the file in a BufferedReader, put everyline in an ArrayList, and then work on that? you wouldn't write a file, and you would be working in your operating memory. You can't "write" without saving, "write" is a method that, as its name says, writes to disk.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt I need to create a file to put data in it.

Comment: @John Why ? You are deleting the file at the end of the request so clearly you don't need to leave it in the file. As I said in my first comment, you should send the CSV file directly to `response.getWriter()`

Comment: You're right ! I have writen directly in the response. I didn't know it was possible . Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `CsvBuilder.writeLine(...)` does only accept an instance of `java.io.Writer`, why not using `java.io.StringWriter` and `java.util.Scanner`?

```
// ...

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
CsvBuilder.writeLine(writer, headers);
CsvBuilder.writeLine(writer, values);
writer.flush();
    
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
   response.getWriter().write(scanner.next() + "\n");
}

// ...
```

However, I think Andrei Makarevich's answer using `response.getWriter()` directly is probably the most forward approach. Although, I'm not sure if the line feeds will be added by `CsvBuilder` since your adding them explicitly!?

Comment: Almost good ! I got the csv but one problem : When there is a space in a sentence, the word after space comes in the next line.. Could you please explain scanner.hasNext() part ?

Comment: `scanner.hasNext()` checks if another line exists and `scanner.next()` gets that line. Don't know why you get a line feed when there is a space within a sentence.

Comment: It works ! I have tried directly :      response.getWriter().write(writer.toString() + "\n"); Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can try, if temporary files are allowed:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("test.csv", ".csv");
```

These files are getting created in the user storage of the system, so like "C:\Users[Username]\AppData" in Windows, or something like that. I don't know the exact path, but that should not be important now.

Check out all the kinds of OutputStreams, that exist in Java, there is more than the FileOutputStream:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html
Check the subclasses.

Comment: Good catch this do the job

Answer (score 4):

You can try to write directly to response:

```java
Writer writer =  response.getWriter();

CsvBuilder.writeLine(writer, headers);
CsvBuilder.writeLine(writer, values);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + csvFile);
```

If that can not be used for some reason and temporary files are also not allowed for you, you can try to use this pretty ugly in-memory variant.

```java
List<Integer> output = new LinkedList<>();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new OutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        output.add(b);
    }
}));
// write all the things via CsvBuilder
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (output.size() > 0) {
            return output.remove(0);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}));
```

Comment: +1 only for the first part. The second part is a bad idea and totally broken since it reads the data back in reverse from what was written. You should just use a StringWriter and a StringReader for that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thank you, fixed the order, and you are right: as I told the second one is bad and ugly

Comment: Almost . I think you 're right I tried to write directly the response but I have only the content of the csv file in my browser. Like a .txt  I don't get a csv file. Any idea ?

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone still looking for the answer, below code worked for me perfectly

Import the below dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below code, im writing data to ByteArrayOutputStream, instead of FileWriter

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(out), ',', Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  String[] data = new String[] { "fieldValueA", "fieldValueB", "fieldValueC" };
  csvWriter.writeRecord(data);
  csvWriter.close();
```

Comment: How about the data is List<Map, String>?

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilderWriter to have a writer instead of FileWriter

```
final Writer writer = new StringBuilderWriter();
```

Comment: Apache Commons `StringBuilderWriter`? Be careful within a multi threaded environment.